# coldfusion/html extra dashes in my output

Tags: html, coldfusion

I've been chasing this one for hours.  I have a report that was working before (and still is) but the output suddenly acquired a line of dashes which wasn't there before.  I have searched and searched for the problem.  Firebug shows the dashes:

```
<div style="margin-top: -30px; margin-left: -50px">
<link href="betty.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
@media print
{
table tr.page-break{page-break-before:always}
@page {margin: 2cm}
</style>
<p> rep2 496 </p>
- - - - - - - - -
<table class="reptable">
</div>
```

and that is exactly what is happening, but I cannot find these dashes, in fact not even one dash in case it's a loop, anywhere in my code.  My code at that point:

```
<div style = "margin-top: -30px; margin-left: -50px">
<cfoutput> #custrep# </cfoutput>
</div>
```

cannot be the problem.  The code where I created custrep looks like this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable = "custrep">
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="betty.css"/>
<style type="text/css">    
 @media print
 {
 table tr.page-break{page-break-before:always}  
 @page {margin: 2cm} 
</style>
<p><cfoutput> rep2 496 </cfoutput> </p>
<table class = "reptable"  >
   lots of stuff
</table>
```

You can see there are no dashes between the `<p>` which is above them and the `<table` which is below them.  the css for reptable

```
.reptable {

border-collapse:separate;
/*  border-spacing: 20px 0px;*/
border-spacing: 10px 0px;

}
```

Can anyone suggest something here to try to find and get rid of these extra dashes?

Comment: can you comment that part of the code and check if the dashes still show up?

Comment: If there is an element "in" the table that is not enclosed in a table cell it will appear _above_ the table. For example, if you have something like `<table><cfoutput>#xyzzy#</cfoutput><tr><td>...` then the contents of `xyzzy` will appear _above_ the table (unless `xyzzy` contains `<tr>` `<td>` tags).

Comment: The dashes appear in the page, or just in Firebug?

Comment: David Faber, I'm well aware of that, and do think it is the problem, but I cannot find any loose dashes in the table.

Comment: Scott Stroz, the dashes appear both in the report and in Firebug.  If they weren't in the report I wouldn't care.

Comment: Sanjeev -- It is so complex that the code will break if I comment out much of it, or maybe any of it.   However, that approach may be preferable to tearing the whole thing apart and adding back one line at a time.

Comment: Betty, you need to use process of elimination, so you're probably going to have to start commenting out parts of suspect code to narrow this down. Otherwise you could waste valuable time speculating in your imagination without acting to prove what's happening. (Also, I hope you have this website mirrored on a staging environment so you are not breaking live code.)

Comment: Adam, you are so right.  I was hoping I could track it down without tearing it apart line by line, since there are many, many lines but that doesn't seem to be in the cards.  I don't have the website mirrored, but all the programs are well backed up.  If I mess up I can restore the original (dash filled) version.

Comment: Just to let all you helpers know -- I did find that extra dash.  It took hours, because the code is intricate and you can't just comment stuff out.  You wind up mismatching your openings and closings on cfif, cfloop and cfoutput statements.  So it was very slow.  But great to see that dash disappear when I finally commented out the right thing.  Thanks all.